# searching for finding the Cognitive Cycle of psychological defence mechanism for bipolar disorders

Tags: bipolar-disorder, cbt

I am searching for finding some pattern for bipolar disorder and online tracking the psychological defense mechanisms and its cycles . So I need some chart or flowchart like below ([source](https://www.eatingenlightenment.com/2019/10/31/cognitive-behavioral-therapy-to-treat-eating-disorders/)):

[image]

Also, I found some paper like : [The Timing of the Cognitive Cycle](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0014803) which is
describing a timing model, LIDA's cognitive cycle, but it is not especially for bipolar disorder.

If possible, I like to find out some comment or answer for finding some tags for finding academic paper for  `finding the Cognitive Cycle of psychological defence mechanism for bipolar disorders`.

Thanks.

Comment: When you are talking about the psychological defense mechanisms, are you talking about them in the Freudian sense or in some other context?

Comment: Thanks, @Chris_Rogers for your attention to these questions. These questions are one part of our trying to track the psychological defense system, and we could go more than Freud defense system classification.